# The input style on iphone is different from PC/Android device

Tags: html, css, iphone, safari

There is a compatibility issue when using the input element.

The number exceeds the range of the input box on iphone

[image: iphone]

But it's normal on Android / PC

[image]

The style as below

```css
html * {
  font-size: 36px !important;
  color: #0 !important;
  font-family: Arial !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.common-flex {
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-box;/* android 2.1-3.0, ios 3.2-4.3 */
  display: -webkit-flex;/* Chrome 21+ */
  display: -ms-flexbox;/* WP IE 10 */
  display:flex;/* android 4.4 */
}

.common-flex-spacebetween {
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;/* android 2.1-3.0, ios 3.2-4.3 */
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;/* Chrome 21+ */
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;/* WP IE 10 */
  justify-content: space-between;/* android 4.4 */
}
```

```html
<div class="common-flex common-flex-spacebetween" style="margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px; padding:0px;" >
  <input name="yy" type="num" id="yy" style="width:110px; text-align:center;" aria-label="year"/>
  <label id="xx1" style="float: center;">/</label>
  <input name="mon" type="num" id="mon" style="width:60px; text-align:center;" aria-label="month"/>
  <label id="xx2" style="float: center;">/</label>
  <input name="dd" type="num" id="dd" style="width:60px; text-align:center;" aria-label="day"/>
</div>
```

How to fix the input style on iphone?
Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

hi king5201 I think you can use media query to style your phone because media query style in your website can responsive design

Answer (score 0):

bare in mind that you are using pixels. It is much more recommended that you either use em or percentages.